# How to add unmanaged library reference to NUnit test

Tags: c#, c++, visual-studio, nunit, clr

**Question:** How do I make native library available to NUnit when running tests, so that it can be loaded on startup?

**Background:** I have started using NUnit for tests recently and I'm struggling to set-up a test which involves unmanaged (native) library (let's call it `x.dll`). The project I'm testing is managed c++/CLI wrapper around this library. I have NUnit c# test project which references the wrapper, so I can use functions defined there. The problem is that when I run test, `System.IO.FileNotFoundException` is thrown, indicating that the `x.dll` couldn't be found. I need to point NUnit to it's location somehow, or make it copy the dll into execution directory (which is hidden somewhere in `temp` directory) but couldn't find how to do that after fairly extensive search - probably missing the right keywords.

I'm using NUnit 3 extension in Visual Studio and the test project was created using template also available as an extension.

Answer (score 0):

The trick to using unmanaged assemblies is to be aware that they are found by the operating system using a different approach from the way that .NET finds managed references.

As a refresher: unmanaged assemblies are found on the path, while managed assemblies are found in the AppBase or private binpath under it.

My guess is that that VS is copying `x.dll` into the output directory. If not, you should make it do so by setting CopyLocal to true. Now, before running your test, add that directory to the start of your path. If you are not already using a script, you'll probably have to create one in order to do that.

Comment: What approach should I use to edit Path (I guess you meant env. variable)? Is it possible to change it just for the application (the test) on startup, or do I have to edit it system-wide? I would like the former - not polluting the system and doesn't force all developers to do it, but I am not sure if its doable.

Comment: The test can't do anything till it loads and it can't load until all references are satisfied. If you run a script to execute the tests, simply add to the PATH environment variable before running nunit3-console.exe. The setting will not effect anything else after your script completes.

Comment: Thank you, but I'm running tests from Visual Studio directly, using Resharper. How would I integrate script running `nunit3-console` with this environment? 

On the side note, I might have managed to set-up exactly what I need thanks to your recap, just need to try it bit more before posting it here.

Answer (score 0):

Because I wanted the tests to be self-contained and able to run using tools like Resharper or Visual Studio Test framework (using NUnit extension), I tried to avoid running tests from script like @Charlie suggested, because I wouldn't know how to integrate results with these tools.

However, I managed to find an interesting attribute `OneTimeSetUpAttribute`, which can be used to mark function so that [it will be ran every time before the tests](https://github.com/nunit/docs/wiki/OneTimeSetUp-Attribute). Thankfully, this is implemented to happen in the same process in which tests are ran, so we can use this to alter Path variable in elegant manner. This is code I use to alter Path, which also allows to distinguish architecture on which they are running:

```
void RegisterLibs()
{
     const string pathVar = "Path";
     const string fileUriTag = "file:///";

     // Get executable path
     var exePath = System.Reflection.Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().CodeBase;
     if (exePath.StartsWith(fileUriTag))
         exePath = exePath.Remove(0, fileUriTag.Length);
     // Extract directory
     var exeDir = System.IO.Path.GetDirectoryName(exePath);

     // Get path variable
     var pathVal = Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable(pathVar) ?? "";
     // Simple check for architecture. 
     // 4-byte pointer => 32bit
     // 8-byte pointer => 64bit
     var arch = IntPtr.Size == 4 ? "Win32" : "x64";
     // Prepare new entry for path
     var libPath = $"{exeDir}\\{arch};";
     if (pathVal.Contains(libPath))
          return;
     // Prepend the entry
     pathVal = pathVal.Insert(0, libPath);
     // Update path variable
     Environment.SetEnvironmentVariable(pathVar, pathVal);
}
```

which can be then used in tests:

```
[TestFixture]
public class UnitTests
{
    [OneTimeSetUpAttribute]
    public void TestFixtureSetup()
    {
        RegisterLibs();
    }

    [Test]
    public void Test1()
    {
        // Path is set-up here
        // ...Your test code...
    }
}
```